# How to apache to stop response to requests if alias or port does not match

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, http, redirect, https

I have more than one domain like example1.com example2.com. Some of them has SSL certificates and some of them does not. My apache listens both 80 and 443. If a domain has SSL certificates, I redirect that domain http requests to https.

But I have trouble with domains which does not have SSL certificates. I don't want apache to response their https requests.

Let's say example1.com has SSL certificate and example2.com does not. If I write https://example2.com to browser, browser sees example1.com SSL certificates. I don't want apache to response that requests. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Apache will always respond to properly formatted requests.  However, if you setup a default SSL virtual host you can return 404 or other error response to all requests.  If the requested domain does not match the supported domains, the response should also trigger and SSL domain mismatch error.